# How to convert .sql file into dump file?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper, toad

I have a file of size 1.2 GB with the extension of .sql
I have created this file with oracle Toad. I want to concert this file into dump file.
Actually my database has been corrupt. I export this data with the help of toad. Now I want this file to import in newly installed database but its extension is sql which I can not handle.

Comment: If you open the file, is it just a bunch of `INSERT` statements?  If so, you're not going to be able to convert it to an export utility dmp file.  But you don't need to, you'd just want to run the statements in the new database.

Answer (score 0):

use following command to restore psql -h  -d <db_name> -U <db_user> -f filename.sql

Comment: `psql` is for PostgreSQL, not for Oracle